# Filtrar array de strings

Tags: javascript

Como eu faço para percorrer um array de nomes utilizando a função filter do javascript em que o retorno seja apenas nomes de pessoas com o sobrenome "Carvalho"?

Exemplo:

```
let nomes = ["Thiago Carvalho", "Renata Carvalho", "Alexandre Otoni", "Guilherme Otoni de Carvalho"];

nomes.filter(item => ???);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o método [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) no filtro. Este método foi implementado no *ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)*, e funciona semelhante ao velho `indexOf`:

```js
let nomes = ["Thiago Carvalho", "Renata Carvalho", "Alexandre Otoni", "Guilherme Otoni de Carvalho"];
let filtro = nomes.filter(item => item.includes("Carvalho"));
console.log(filtro);
```

[**DOCUMENTAÇÃO**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: Obrigado, era justamente a solução que procurava!

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que o sobrenome é o ultimo nome, pode dividir os nomes com `split(" ")` e obter o ultimo com `slice(-1)` e verificar se é o que pretende:

```js
let nomes = ["Thiago Carvalho", "Renata Carvalho", "Alexandre Otoni", "Guilherme Otoni de Carvalho"];

let filtro = "Carvalho";
let nomesFiltrados = nomes.filter(item => item.split(" ").slice(-1) == filtro);
console.log(nomesFiltrados);
```

Documentação para o [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) e [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira usar [expressões regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), deixo aqui um exemplo de como  fazê-lo:

```js
const nomes = ['Thiago Carvalho', 'Renata Carvalho', 'Alexandre Otoni', 'Guilherme Otoni de Carvalho'];

const filtro = 'Carvalho';
const nomesFiltrados = nomes.filter(item => (new RegExp(filtro)).test(item));

console.log(nomesFiltrados);
```

Documentação para os métodos utilizados:

- [`Filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro);
- [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp);
- [`Test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).