# Como encontrar strings dentro de um array

Tags: javascript, lógica

Bom dia!

Eu tenho o seguinte array:

`const keys = ["idCard1", "idCard2", "idCard3",  "oi", "idCard4"]`

Eu preciso guardar em outro array apenas o que começa com a palavra "idCard", seria possível?

Tentativa do usuário:

```
let keys = [idCard1, idCard2, idCard3,  oi, idCard4]
let filtro = keys.filter(item => item.includes("idCard"));
console.log(filtro);
```

<sup>Essa tentativa havia sido colocada no campo de respostas.</sup>

Comment: function isBigEnough(value) {
  return value >= 10;
}

var filtered = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44].filter(isBigEnough);
// filtrado é [12, 130, 44]

Comment: Mas eu quero pegar tudo que começa com a palavra "idCard", essa função serviria?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Filtrar array de strings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292455/filtrar-array-de-strings)

Comment: let nomes = ["Thiago Carvalho", "Renata Carvalho", "Alexandre Otoni", "Guilherme Otoni de Carvalho"];
let filtro = nomes.filter(item => item.includes("Carvalho"));
console.log(filtro);

Comment: Muita calma nessa hora, isso aqui `const keys = [idCard1, idCard2, idCard3,  oi, idCard4]` não é um array de strings, é um array composto pelo valor de várias variáveis que podem ou não ser strings.

Comment: Postei o teste do código, o qual não funcionou

Comment: Eu não apresentei uma tenteativa, eu não dou chutes. Eu estou alertando que isso que você colocou na pergunta `const keys = [idCard1, idCard2, idCard3,  oi, idCard4]` não é um array de strings é um array de variáveis.

Comment: Um array de strings seria assim `const keys = ["idCard1", "idCard2", "idCard3",  "oi", "idCard4"]`. Então pergunto você tem certeza que a primeira forma apresentada está correta?

Comment: Voce esta correto, a minha forma de enviar aqui realmente foi errada. O meu array é de strings, mas eu o trouxe aqui como variável. Mesmo assim, teria como eu procurar o que preciso?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e deixe da maneira correta e me marque num comentário depois da edição que ao voltar do almoço o dou uma resposta. Isso se alguém já não tiver o respondido após a edição.

Comment: Pronto, Augusto. Já editei. Agradeceria muito se conseguisse me ajudar. Desde já, obrigado

Answer (score 3):

Use o método [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro) para cria um novo array com todos os elementos que passaram no teste fornecido em uma função passado como parâmetro para `filter()`.

Para implementar o teste use a o método [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) que determina se uma string começa com os caracteres especificados retornando true ou false.

```js
const keys = ["idCard1", "idCard2", "idCard3", "oi", "idCard4"]

let result = keys.filter((e) => e.startsWith("idCard"));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra maneira de resolver este problema é utilizando uma estrutura de laço for em conjunto com o método [startsWith](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) do javascript.

Segue um exemplo:

```
const chave = ['idCard1', 'idCard2', 'idCard3',  'oi', 'idCard4']
const result = []
for (let k = 0; k < chave.length;k++) {
    if  (chave[k].startsWith('idCard')) {
        result.push(chave[k])
    }
}
console.log(result)
```